# Writing $\mathbb{R}$ as a countable union of closed intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This is probably trivial, but I need to know if my reasoning is correct.

$\mathbb{R} = \displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} [ -i,i]$

If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $x \in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \subseteq (-i,i) \subseteq[-i,i]$ for some natural $i$, so $x \in \displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}[-i,i]$.

If $x \in \displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}[-i,i]$, then there is a natural such that $x \in [-i,i] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Hence the sets are equal.

Is everything ok with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes! looks fine to me

Comment: It looks generally ok, but a bit weird that the intervals are just increasing in both directions.  For all $j\lt i$ you get that the union over the intervals for $j$ is entirely contained in the one interval for $i$.  You might consider writing your interval as $[i-1,i+1]$...

Comment: Probably ([tag:solution-verification]) might be a suitable tag here.

Comment: @abiessu What's weird about it? The question doesn't say "with empty intersections" or something like that. Having an increasing (wrt containment) sequence of sets might even make some proofs simpler.

Comment: @lisyarus good point, it just seems weird and feels like it creates "vacuous truth" situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course, in particular, $\ \varepsilon = \min\{\ \lceil {x} \rceil - x,\ x - \lfloor {x \rfloor }\ \} $ is probably what you're after.

Also, whilst what you say is true, it's not how I would prove that $\mathbb{R} = \displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} [ -i,i],\ $ assuming that was what you were trying to do. For the first part, I would say:

If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $x \in [\ -\lceil {\small{|}x\small{|}} \rceil\ ,\ \lceil {\small{|}x\small{|}} \rceil\ \ ] = [-i,\ i]\ $ for some $i \in \mathbb{N} \cup\{0\}.$

Your last sentence is fine.